# Send sms using Mbn Api C#

Tags: c#, windows, sms

I'm looking for a way to send Sms throught MbnApi using :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323167(v=vs.85).aspx
IMbnSms interface. But it's not working at all. 
I could not have a sample project to see how to do it. I'm coding on C# .Net

Thx

```
public  class NaErrorHandling
{
   public Dictionary<UInt32, string> Hresults { get;private set; }

   public NaErrorHandling()
   {
       Hresults = new Dictionary<UInt32, string>();
       Init();
   }

   private void Init()
   {
       Hresults.Add(0, "S_OK");
       Hresults.Add(0x8054820a, "E_MBN_SIM_NOT_INSERTED");
       Hresults.Add(0x80070057, "E_INVALIDARG");
       Hresults.Add(0x80548202, "E_MBN_BAD_SIM");

       Hresults.Add(0x80548210, "E_MBN_PIN_REQUIRED");
       Hresults.Add(0x80548224, "E_MBN_SMS_MEMORY_FAILURE");
       Hresults.Add(0x80548226, "E_MBN_SMS_UNKNOWN_SMSC_ADDRESS");
       Hresults.Add(0x80548209, "E_MBN_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVATED");
       Hresults.Add(0x80548225, "E_MBN_SMS_NETWORK_TIMEOUT");
       Hresults.Add(0x8054820d, "E_MBN_NOT_REGISTERED");
       Hresults.Add(0x80548223, "E_MBN_SMS_LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED");
       Hresults.Add(0x80548220, "E_MBN_SMS_ENCODING_NOT_SUPPORTED");
       Hresults.Add(0x80548228, "E_MBN_SMS_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED");
       Hresults.Add(0x80548229, "E_MBN_SMS_MEMORY_FULL");
       Hresults.Add(0X80070015, "ERROR_NOT_READY");

       Hresults.Add(1062, "ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE");
   }
   public string GetError(int error)
   {
       UInt32 uerror = (UInt32)error;
       if (Hresults.ContainsKey(uerror))
           return Hresults[uerror];
       return "Error Not Know";
   }
}

 public class SmsResult : MbnApi.IMbnSmsEvents 
{
    public void OnSetSmsConfigurationComplete(MbnApi.IMbnSms sms, uint requestID, int status)
    {
    }

    public void OnSmsConfigurationChange(MbnApi.IMbnSms sms)
    {
    }

    public void OnSmsDeleteComplete(MbnApi.IMbnSms sms, uint requestID, int status)
    {
    }

    public void OnSmsNewClass0Message(MbnApi.IMbnSms sms, MbnApi.MBN_SMS_FORMAT SmsFormat, object[] readMsgs)
    {

    }

    public void OnSmsReadComplete(MbnApi.IMbnSms sms, MbnApi.MBN_SMS_FORMAT SmsFormat, object[] readMsgs, bool moreMsgs, uint requestID, int status)
    {
        string messageShow = String.Empty;
        SMSPDULib.SMS rms= new SMSPDULib.SMS();

        foreach (var msgReceived in readMsgs)
        {
            var msg = msgReceived as IMbnSmsReadMsgPdu;
           messageShow +=  GetSms(msg.PduData) + "\n";
        }
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show( messageShow);
    }


    private string GetSms(string pduSource)
    {
        SMSType smsType = SMSBase.GetSMSType(pduSource);
        string message = string.Empty;
        switch (smsType)
        {
            case SMSType.SMS:
                SMS sms = new SMS();
                SMS.Fetch(sms, ref pduSource);
                message = sms.Message;
                //Use instance of SMS class here
                break;
            case SMSType.StatusReport:
                SMSStatusReport statusReport = new SMSStatusReport();
                SMSStatusReport.Fetch(statusReport, ref pduSource);
                //Use instance of SMSStatusReport class here
                break;
        }
        return message;
    }
    public void OnSmsSendComplete(MbnApi.IMbnSms sms, uint requestID, int status)
    {
        NaErrorHandling handling = new NaErrorHandling();
        var res = handling.GetError(status);
        UInt32 uStatus = (UInt32)status;
    }

    public void OnSmsStatusChange(MbnApi.IMbnSms sms)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public void SendSms()
    {
        MbnConnectionManager mbnConnectionMgr = new MbnConnectionManager();
        IMbnConnectionManager connMgr = (IMbnConnectionManager)mbnConnectionMgr;
        try
        {
            IMbnConnection[] arrConn = connMgr.GetConnections();
            if (arrConn != null)
            {
                String res = String.Empty;
                foreach (var connection in arrConn)
                {
                    res += String.Format("Connection ID : {0} | Interface Id : {1}\n", connection.ConnectionID, connection.InterfaceID);
                }
                //MessageBox.Show(res);
                var conn = arrConn[0];
                uint prId = 0;
                //conn.Connect(MBN_CONNECTION_MODE.MBN_CONNECTION_MODE_PROFILE, "Bouygues Telecom", out prId);
                MbnInterfaceManager mbnInterfaceMgr = new MbnInterfaceManager();
                var mbnInterface = mbnInterfaceMgr as IMbnInterfaceManager;
                var selectInterface = mbnInterface.GetInterface(conn.InterfaceID);
                MBN_INTERFACE_CAPS caps =  selectInterface.GetInterfaceCapability();

                var theCap =caps.smsCaps;// (uint)MBN_SMS_CAPS.MBN_SMS_CAPS_PDU_SEND;
                IConnectionPointContainer icpc;
                icpc = (IConnectionPointContainer)mbnInterfaceMgr;

                Guid IID_IMbnConnectionEvents = typeof(IMbnSmsEvents).GUID;
                IConnectionPoint icp;
                icpc.FindConnectionPoint(ref IID_IMbnConnectionEvents, out icp);

                SmsResult connEvtsSink = new SmsResult();
                uint cookie;
                icp.Advise(connEvtsSink, out cookie);


                var sms = selectInterface as IMbnSms;
                string phoneDest = "";
                string pdu = String.Empty;
                byte[] size = new byte[5];

                uint requestId = 456;
                MBN_SMS_STATUS_INFO smsStatusInfo = new MBN_SMS_STATUS_INFO();
                smsStatusInfo.flag = 10;
                try
                {
                    IMbnSmsConfiguration smsConfig = sms.GetSmsConfiguration();
                    sms.GetSmsStatus(out smsStatusInfo);

                    var wtf = smsStatusInfo;
                    string serviceDatacenter = smsConfig.ServiceCenterAddress;
                    CreatePduSms(null, phoneDest, "Hello", out pdu, out size);

                    //var res1 = SMSPDULib.SMS.GetBytes(pdu, 16);
                    var total = SMSPDULib.SMS.GetBytes(pdu);
                    byte wantedSize =(byte) total.Length;

                    CreatePduSms(serviceDatacenter, phoneDest, "Hello", out pdu, out size);
                    //var byteArray = StringToByteArray(pdu);
                    //var str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7.GetString(byteArray);

                    sms.SmsSendPdu(pdu, wantedSize, out requestId); 
                    //sms.SmsSendCdma(phoneDest, MBN_SMS_CDMA_ENCODING.MBN_SMS_CDMA_ENCODING_7BIT_ASCII, MBN_SMS_CDMA_LANG.MBN_SMS_CDMA_LANG_FRENCH, 2, GetBytes("Hi"), out requestId);
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Cannot send Message : " + exp.Message);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private void CreatePduSms(string servAddress, string phoneDest, string msg, out string pdu, out byte[] size)
    {

        SMSPDULib.SMS sms = new SMSPDULib.SMS();
        sms.Direction = SMSPDULib.SMSDirection.Submited;
        sms.PhoneNumber = "";
        if (servAddress != null)
        sms.ServiceCenterNumber = servAddress;
        sms.ValidityPeriod = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0, 0);
        sms.Message = msg + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        pdu = sms.Compose(SMSPDULib.SMS.SMSEncoding._7bit);
        size = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Share some code, what have you tried?

Comment: Does it have to be via the Mbn api?  it strikes me that there are far easier ways (such as Twilo) that provide easy to use C# development kits, all ready with easy to understand samples.

Comment: Could you find any solution? I'm also trying with MbnApi with no success.

Comment: I was able to send and receive SMS's using an Universal Windows Application compiled for x64 platform, using Windows.Devices.Sms namespace. 
Example here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmsSendAndReceive